# Migrate from Play 2.0.4 to 2.1: Tika doesn't find my class anymore

Tags: scala, playframework, classpath, apache-tika, playframework-2.1

I migrated a web application from Play Framework 2.0.4 to 2.1.

The application uses [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) (V. 1.3) with a custom parser as described [here](http://tika.apache.org/1.3/parser_guide.html) on the Tika-Homepage.

A file `myPlayProject/conf/META-INF/services/org.apache.tika.parser.Parser`contains the name of the custom parser class like this:

```
# Add here all custom parsers for Apache Tika.

com.test.CustomTikaParser
```

The custom parser will get detected with Play 2.0.4, but not anymore with Play 2.1. I have tried it with two fresh 2.0.4vs2.1-projects and got the same problem with V. 2.1.

**Has something changed with the classpath between these Play versions?**

(I can read the file `META-INF/services/org.apache.tika.parser.Parser` with Play 2.0.4 and Play 2.1 under the classpath.)

Comment: The classloader from Play 2.1 didn't load the `com.test.CustomTikaParser` class. Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: Is there a chance that you forgot to configure something with the project dependencies? Since Play 2.1, they have to be explicitely specified (see http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/Migration). You may also try to make a `clean` to your Play project.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try a simple command :

play clean-all update reload compile,

it will be clean your .target do an update and reload of your application then a compile...